# Why is sqllite3 giving an index error when using between dates statement?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database of futures contract daily data.  Columns are id, stock_id, datetime, open, high, low, close.

I'm using a python environment and when I try to pull the data the following way, I get an error:

```
start_date = '2019-01-02'  
end_date = '2021-12-09'
def get_data():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("E:\\stock_db\\app.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print("pulling data from", connection)
    margin_table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from margin_table", connection)
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from es_daily where (datetime BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}');".format(start_date, end_date), connection)
    return df
df = get_data()
```

The error reads:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

When I take the `between` statement out, it pulls everything fine.  This leads me to believe I'm not doing hte between statement correctly.

Is there something wrong with the select statement?

Comment: Please, post full traceback you get.

Comment: What's the reason for the `margin_table` query? You never do anything with that dataframe.

Comment: What that implies is that there were no records between those two dates.  Remember that sqlite doesn't understand dates; every item is a string.   Is your `datetime` column formatted exactly like that, YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: As mentioned in comment by @Barmar (but deleted) - don't use string formatting, but parametrized query, something like  - `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from es_daily where datetime BETWEEN ? AND ?;", connection, params=(start_date, end_date))`

Comment: @buran I deleted it because I was thinking of `cursor.execute()` and didn't know the equivalent for `pd.read_sql_query()`

Comment: @TimRoberts pandas can't create an empty dataframe when the query returns no rows?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I figured that. Nevertheless the main point about parametrized query was legit. :-)